# Did Deadpool select all of the people who come to join X-force?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2

We see in *Deadpool 2* that Deadpool is casting people to fight Cable and save the boy. Weasel says in one scene that it's time to get back on Linked-In.

So they put on audition and selected some of the applicants.

Did Deadpool interview anybody who didn't subsequently join X-Force?

Comment: We have no way of knowing unless this is shown in the movie...which AFAIK it isn't.

Comment: Considering they recruited *two* persons with no superpowers (they didn't believe that luck is a superpower, so they recruited domino considering she had no superpower), it is safe to assume they scrapped the barrel and recruited everyone they could.

Comment: Are you looking for something that may have been on a director's cut or edit reel or are you looking for an in movie answer?

Answer (score 11):

> Did Deadpool interview anybody who didn't subsequently join X-Force?

Well, kind of. While we do not see any unsuccessful interviews, there is the case of [Dopinder](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Dopinder), who clearly wanted to be on the team, but was rejected.

Comment: Based on how the X-Force outing ended, I'd say Dopinder kinda lucked out on this one :)